# Crear un método dentro de un objeto para hacer cálculos de unos datos

Tags: javascript

function crearClaseViajero() {

class Viajero {

constructor(nombre, edad, paises, compañeros)

getPromedioEdad() {

```
  // El método 'getPromedioEdad' debe retornar el promedio de edad de los compañeros de un viajero.
  // Ej:
  // Si el viajero tuviera estos compañeros:
  // {
  //   compañeros: [{
  //     nombre: 'John',
  //     nacionalidad: "Australiano",
  //     edad: 27,
  //   }, {
  //     nombre: 'Peter',
  //     nacionalidad: "Belga",
  //     edad: 23
  //   }]
  // }
  // viajero.getPromedioEdad() debería devolver 25 ya que (27 + 23) / 2 = 25
```

Comment: Cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: ahi estaria mejor la pregunta

Comment: La funcion getPromedioEdad debera recorrer el array compañeros e ir sumando todas las edades de cada uno de ellos. Finalmente divide esa sumatorio entre el length del array compañeros. Las dos variables a tener en cuenta, principalmente, son : 1- Sumatorio de la edad de los compañeros. 2- La cantidad total de compañeros de viajero en cuestion.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. Quizá te ayude leer [ask]. Deberías de plantearte, en función de que la pregunta no está del todo clara, ya que no aportas código, que tipo de propiedad es compañeros, para un objeto viajero. ¿Cuantos?. ¿Debería de ser dinámica?. Luego bien sea cuando construyes el viajero, o mediante un "seteo" de su propiedad le inyectas los viajeros. Y el método getPromedio, ya podrá recorrer/calcular ese promedio.

Answer (score 0):

Senzillo, y puro javascript para que puedas empezar a trabajar y aprender en ello

```js
viajero = new Object()
viajero.companeros = [{ nombre: 'John', nacionalidad: "Australiano", edad: 27, },{ nombre: 'Peter', nacionalidad: "Belga", edad: 23 }] 

viajero.getPromedioEdad = function () { 
 var edades = 0
 this.companeros.map(function(obj){
    edades += obj.edad;
    })
    edades = edades / this.companeros.length;
    return edades;
    }
console.log(viajero.getPromedioEdad())
```

[Testealo en lina](https://jsfiddle.net/jvu9fytd/)